# Expand macro in C++ with lsp code action in Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, language-server-protocol

With lsp you can replace a macro with its replacement from the preprocessor: lsp-execute-code-action "expand macro", but is it possible to implement a function on elisp'e, that it would not replace the macro in the code, but open a separate buffer next to it, where it would insert the expanded macro? How is this done in Clion! Сould you write it?

Answer (score 2):

This feature exists.

You may call it with `lsp-ui-doc-glance`.

[Please refer to the docs](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-ui/)

Comment: `lsp-ui-doc-glance` in my editor only shows the name of the macro, but it doesn't show what it's expanded into! The clang compiler.

Comment: [Here is how it looks for me](https://imgur.com/a/zTvm1x2). I use clangd too @HamsterGamer